# Placing / Positioning the Virtual Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I want the Keyboard to appear in a certain position within my App.

It's pretty simple to place a `KeyboardView` in your Activity as you would any other `View`:

```
        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"/>
```

Add to that the ability to plug this `KeyboardView` into the rest of the device:

```
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

        @Override public void swipeUp() {}

        @Override public void swipeRight() {}

        @Override public void swipeLeft() {}

        @Override public void swipeDown() {}

        @Override public void onText(CharSequence text) {}

        @Override public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {}

        @Override public void onPress(int primaryCode) {}

        @Override
        public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode));
        }
    });
```

My problem is I **don't** want to specify my own `Keyboard` object like so:

```
mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty));
```

Instead of using my `Keyboard` (which will have it's own style / layout / etc) I want to keep the user as comfortable and at home as possible by using the `Keyboard` which is used everywhere else on the device.

Does anybody know how I gain access to either the `Keyboard` object or the standard `android.R.xml.keyboard` resource from which the keyboard is built?

(or, perversely, if anyone know's how to place the standard keyboard in a way other than the one above I'd be happy with that! :))